# react-native-vector-icons font awesome and light version

Tags: react-native, icons, font-awesome

I want to display font awesome icon in my app and am using react-native-vector-icons to do it.
Unfortunately, it seems like it is displaying the solid version of the icon where I want the light version. How can I choose to display the light version?

```
<Icon
    style={styles.icon}
    name={this.props.iconName}
    size={30}
    color="white"
/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up solving it by using the fontAwesome5 that is included which allows to specify the version of the font

Answer (score 0):

Do you try change fontWeight style?